# Navigate to new page with javascript and disable menus/fullscreen

Tags: javascript, redirect, resize, window, fullscreen

I have an interesting problem where I need to redirect to a page that needs to be fullscreen with menu's disabled.  Normally I would use window.open() but I either want the original page to close (without promt) or for the original page to navigate to this new page.

I tried window.open("index.htm", "_self", "fullscreen, menubar=no, status=no) and opens the new page in the original menu but doesn't satisfy any of the other parameters.

window.location will not let me use the windowing options either

(the user will be using IE exclusively for this purpose)

Thanks!

Comment: You can't force that to happen, at least not to all your victims. I mean users. Some browsers will let you control some of that, but ultimately it's up to the browser owner.

Comment: Most browser don't allow this nowadays. What you want is generally regarded as bad practice because it can confuse and irritate the user.

Comment: I only need to worry about Internet Explorer for this case, and this is for a very specific application.  Its not malicious I promise!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that it only has to work in IE, then you can use this script:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.SendKeys("{F11}");
</script>
```

You have to make the website a trusted site for this to work, and you have to enable "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting".

Comment: This might be a solution we can use if there are no other options.  I generally stay away from activeX calls.  What I don't understand is why I can call window.open and the minute i target _self none of the other parameters work.